# How to run gatling scenarios sequentially?

Tags: java, scala, e2e-testing, gatling

I have 2 scenarios and i want scenario-2 execute after the scenario-1 finished.

Gatling documenation Says:

> Sequential Scenarios It’s also possible with andThen to chain
> scenarios so that children scenarios starts once all the users in the
> parent scenario terminate.

```
val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Scenario-1 ***")
    .exec{ComputerScenarios.scnCheckSerialNumberIsValidForComputerDeletion(serialNumber)}
    .exec(pause(1.minutes))

  val scn2: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Scenario-2")
    .exec(ComputerScenarios.scnCheckSerialNumberIsValidForComputerDeletion(serialNumber2))


  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).andThen(scn2.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))).maxDuration(60).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

When i run this test, both scenario executes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, I think you're chaining the 'andThen' in the wrong scope

so instead of

```
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).andThen(scn2.inject(atOnceUsers(1))))
```

try

```
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1).andThen(scn2.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))))
```